# SQLalchemy, Flask, Python, Connections not being returned to the pool

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I am having trouble figuring out SQLalchemy--I switched from flask-SQLalchemy to SQLalchemy for some more flexibility--but I may just get rid of the SQLalchemy wrapper altogether if I can't figure this out.

I am using the declarative pattern from this guide: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/

## Initapp.py

```
    #main app
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful
from flask_s3 import FlaskS3

import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
'''
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
'''
app = Flask(__name__)

def my_on_checkout(dbapi_conn, connection_rec, connection_proxy):
    print "checkout",dbapi_conn

def my_on_checkin(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    print "checkin",dbapi_connection

#database
engine = create_engine("postgres://localhost:5432/schmoozeedb", convert_unicode=True, pool_size=20, max_overflow=0, echo=False)    
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

# for just 1 load of our app, number of checkouts from the engine pool does not equal number of checkins -- are things not getting
# returned to our connection pool?
event.listen(engine, 'checkout', my_on_checkout)
event.listen(engine, 'checkin', my_on_checkin)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

## Webapp.py

```
@app.route('/demo2/<user_email>/<zip_code>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def demo2(user_email=None, zip_code=None):
    # do some stuff which interacts with a db then render a template
    # the template starts polling the server until polling is complete
    return render_template('cardangular2.html', ssId = ssId, data = rlayer.hgetall(ssId))

# this is how I am closing the sessions.
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    print 'closing session'
    db_session.remove()
```

## Logs

from initapp.py I have the event listeners and here is what I am noticing and here is my problem:  There are 5 checkouts from the connection pool and only 3 checkins even after the polling is complete and the page is no longer interacting with the server.  Just fyi, the /canvaslocal2/update is just the poller, it finished after 5 polls in this instance.

```
checkout <connection object at 0x108c192b0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkout <connection object at 0x108c19770; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkout <connection object at 0x108c198a0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkout <connection object at 0x108c19640; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkin <connection object at 0x108c192b0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:23] "GET /demo2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
checkout <connection object at 0x108c192b0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkin <connection object at 0x108c198a0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkin <connection object at 0x108c19770; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
storeFeedWrapper: 0.352962970734 s
closing session
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:23] "POST /canvaslocal2/update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
storeFeedWrapper: 0.373705148697 s
storeFeedWrapper: 0.541649103165 s
closing session
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:24] "POST /canvaslocal2/update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
closing session
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:25] "POST /canvaslocal2/update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
storeFeedWrapper: 2.3683412075 s
closing session
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:26] "POST /canvaslocal2/update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
storeFeedWrapper: 3.85505199432 s
storeFeedWrapper: 4.00069713593 s
aggAllFeeds total operation: 4.00373697281 s
aggAllFeeds: 4.00382304192 s
closing session
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 14:31:27] "POST /canvaslocal2/update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

## Closing

When I stop my Server (ctrl+C):

```
checkin <connection object at 0x108c192b0; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
checkin <connection object at 0x108c19640; dsn: 'dbname=schmoozeedb host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>
```

The remaining connections check themselves back in.

I am not a db or SQLalchemy expert--anyone have any idea?  I have a test class where I make 50 requests to /demo2 in webapp. And because of this problem where there is some sort of checkin leakage, I can't pass the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason is this: A connection is "checked out" for each thread, not for each request.

Say for example Flask spins up 5 threads to serve your requests. When the load is lower, it reduces the thread pool to 3. At that point, you'll only see two checkins. The rest of the connections won't be checked back in until their threads close, which is happening when your application exits.